# SyntaxError: JSON.parse en $(document).ready();

Tags: php, jquery, json

este error ya me lo habia dado antes y estaba corregido, en este caso ahora si selecciono un elemento de un select me debe de hacer un $_POST para que me cargue lo que esté relacionado con ese select que en este caso seria una sub categoria el codigo es el siguiente

en mi html tengo este select

```
<div class="row center-align">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6 push-l2">
        <select name="categoria" id="categoria">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Elija una Categoria</option>
//lo que esta entre las llaves es codigo de un framework que se llama smarty
            {section name="cat" loop=$book_categoria.count}
            <option value="{$book_categoria[cat].id}">{$book_categoria[cat].texto}</option>
            {/section}
        </select>

    </div>
```

en el archivo javascript tengo lo siguiente, a diferencia de codigo anterior en este caso lo tengo dentro del `$(document).ready();`

```
     $("select[name=categoria]").change(function(){

        var id_book_categoria =  $(this).val();
        $.post(".select_categoria_subcategoria.php", {id_book_categoria:id_book_categoria},
        function(response){
            console.log(response);
//aqui es cuando da el error JSON.parse
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);
            // $('#rta').html(response);
        });

    });
```

a donde recibe el `$_POST` tengo lo siguiente

```
$book_subcategoria = lista_book_subcategorias('',$conn);
// var_dump($book_subcategoria);
$sub_cats=[];
var_dump($_POST['id_book_categoria']);

for ($i=0; $i < $book_subcategoria['count']; $i++) { 
    if ($_POST['id_book_categoria'] == $book_subcategoria[$i]['id_book_categoria']) {
        if($book_subcategoria[$i]['status']!=66){
            $sub_cats[] = array(
                'id' => $book_subcategoria[$i]['id'],
                'texto' => $book_subcategoria[$i]['texto'],

            );
        }

    }
}
echo json_encode($sub_cats,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

lo que es imprimir en el .PHP el JSON lo hace bien no entiendo la razón puede que sea una tonteria pero yo no veo el error debido a que ya he hecho cosas parecidas.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escribe siempre tu `JSON.parse` como:

```
try {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
}catch(e){
    console.log(e, response);
    return false; // para evitar errores posteriores al parseo
}
```

De esta forma podrás controlar el error y ver cuál es.

[**Try catch JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

Comment: Gracias!!! lo acabo de hacer,  y ya he visto el error jaja un saludo.

Comment: @juank acepta la respuesta si es válida, ¿no?

Comment: @juank [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Márcala como válida si consideras que tu pregunta está solventada. Los comentarios son para aclarar dudas sobre las preguntas/respuestas.